# How to Integrate Zend framework 2 into Netbeans 7.2 IDE

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-7.2

when i download the Zend framework package, it does not contain the zf.bat or zf.php or zf.sh files. Netbeans  requires a path to the zf.bat file of zend framework. Does anyone knows how to integrate the Zendframework 2 in to the Netbeans 7.2 PHP IDE? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a [new plugin for ZF2](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/46432/php-zend-framework-2) but it requires [NetBeans 7.3](http://netbeans.org/features/php/index.html).

Comment: Wow another current, useful question - of course it's closed as "not constructive"

Comment: Exactly.  Really trying to understand how this was closed because it solicits debate or opinion?  He/She asked a very simple fact based question.  This is a real problem on SO.  +1 from me.

Comment: It's a recent problem that is getting worse and worse. Pay attention come election time - anyone but Will...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netbeans 7.2 and even 7.3 don't have a plugin to support Zend framework 2.
I searched ZF2 documentation and there is no zf.sh tool available.
The recommendation is to get the app skelleton from zend svn or git repository.