# php IDE working with ZEND Framework 2

Tags: php, ide, zend-framework2

As we can see here : [How to integrate Zend 2 intto netbean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405928/how-to-integrate-zend-framework-2-into-netbeans-7-2-ide), today there is no way to use ZF2 in neatbean.

I'm still not very friendly with php IDEs but I'm searching for a free IDE natively supporting ZF2.

Comment: Define natively supporting ZF2. There is not a single IDE yet that has features like "New ZF2 Project" (creates file/folder structures for ZF2 Project). However there are multiple IDEs supporting IntelliSense Features simply by scanning all the code you have inside a project. Personally i work with PHP Storm ( http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/ ) but there are multiple other choices

Comment: When we creat a php project in netbean, we can check "Zend project", and in php netbean congfiguration we can specifie the zend framework path (but only zend 1)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse PDT works, but you have to download [Eclipse Juno](http://www.eclipse.org/juno/)
then in Eclipse install new Software and select PDT 3.1.1
Older version available on www.zend.com/en/community/pdt didn't work for me.